# oracle performance on date range query

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-11g, query-performance

I am trying to count the number of orders passed by a certain organization over a certain time range. But I found that the below query (time range of 2 days) is much much slower that doing two seperate queries each for one day.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM ORDER_HISTORY
 WHERE organization = 'BA' AND  TIMESTAMP > = TO_DATE('2016-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
 AND TIMESTAMP<= TO_DATE('2016-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD')+2;
```

I've an index on the column `timestamps` and another index on column `organization`

[image]

Here is the schema of my table. the column `timestamp` is of type `DATE`.

[image]

The execution plan of query over 2 days uses the index on `organization`:

[image]

The execution plan of query over 1 day uses the index on `timestamp`:

[image]

To have some stats:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM ORDER_HISTORY
   WHERE ORGANIZATION = 'BA' ;
```

gives 2359847.

```
   SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM ORDER_HISTORY
   WHERE TIMESTAMP > = TO_DATE('2016-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
   AND TIMESTAMP<= TO_DATE('2016-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD')+1;
```

gives 9260. and same query over 2 days gives 16510.

Why could I get the kind of strange behaviour of the oracle DB engine?

Comment: Have your tables been recently analyzed?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the cost-based optimizer has a plan in memory from a previous select, where the number of records for a given organization, namely 'LOL', was much smaller, some 14000.  When the plan is in memory, the CBO doesn't care about the parameter values anymore.  Use:

```
WHERE organization || '' = 'BA'
```

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille: It's extremely unlikely - even if the old Oracle version (pre 11g) is used, so bind peeking potentially could be the case (and cursor sharing mode was set to force - note , literals , not bind variables ), both queries would have exactly the same plan because the only difference between them is `+1` vs `+2`   which in both cases replaced by something like  `+ "SYS_B_0"`

Comment: @a1ex07 you can see how unlikely in the predicates: "organization='LOL'". The same plan is the problem.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  In the question , there are 2 queries , the only difference is `+1` vs `+2`  . They generate 2 different plans.  So unless I'm missing something, 2 plans are the problem.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille :  Ha , just now I noticed that 'LOL' was in screenshot .   It shouldn't make any difference though - bind peeking would lead to 1 plan, not 2.

Comment: @a1ex07 Notice the difference between  2359847 and 14898.  CBO is using a plan that was suitable for the latter to execute a query for the former.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: You're wrong. 1. 14898 is an estimated number of rows, NOT a number of rows from previous `select`. (as well as 6250  is an estimated number of rows and not equal to actual 9260  )  2. When literals are used instead of bind variables ('LOL', 'BA' , '2016-01-05') , Oracle performs a hard parse and can generate a new plan every time which is exactly what happened according to screenshots in question .

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that optimizer statistics is either out of date, or you have a data skew(i.e. you have popular and unpopular in ORGANIZATION column). Optimizer estimates that filter `ORGANIZATION = 'BA'`  returns 14898 rows which is way different from actual result.  `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats` should fix the issue. 
** According to screenshot it seems that "LOL"  is a value of organization used with `EXPLAIN` , I'd suggest posting actual execution plan .

You may also create extended statistics on 2 columns (ORGANIZATION , timestamp).

Also, always check actual execution plan (`dbms_xplan.display_cursor`), not the result of `explain` .

***Update***

One more thing that may help investigating the problem. 
I also suggest finding query (or queries ) in `v$sql` /`v$sqlarea` and check their cost .  Also, `v$sql` has `is_bind_aware` and `is_bind_sensitive` columns which shows whether optimizer considers and uses different plans depends on different values of bind variables.  Other details about why multiple plans were generated `V$SQL_SHARED_CURSOR` system view that shows why existing child cursor wasn't shared with a new one.

Comment: 14898 is for organization LOL